# A basic question on $L^p$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Consider a probability space and $f_m$ be sequence of measurable functions a.s. converging to $f$. What can be said about the limit

$$ \lim_{m\to \infty} \|f_m\|_m$$

where $\|.\|_p$ stands for the $L^p$ norm?

I don't want answer. Hint Enough.

Comment: For $\to$, use the commands \to or \rightarrow.

Comment: @CameronWilliams:ok

Comment: @CameronWilliams: No, it is pointwise convergence on a probability 1 set.

Comment: Don't think you can say anything: One can show that for all $c>0$, there is a sequence $f_m$ so that $f_m \to 0$ pointwisely a.e. and $||f_m||_m = c$ for all $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything can happen. Take $f_m:=c_m\chi_{(0,a_m)} $ where $a_m\to 0$ and the unit interval is endowed with the Lebesgue measure.

- If $c_m=C a_m^{-1/m} $, the limit is $C$;
- if $c_m=m a_m^{-1/m}$, the limit is infinite;
- if $c_m=(-1)^ma_m^{-1/m}$, the limit does not exist.